# Как сохранить файл в External storage?

Tags: java, android, файлы

В своем приложении я пытаюсь сохранить в память файл с некоторой информацией. Пользователь затем должен иметь возможность найти этот файл и, например, передать его куда-нибудь. Версия Android 8+.

Я сохраняю файл таким образом:

```
    private final static String FILE_NAME = "document.txt";
    
    private File getExternalPath() {
        return new File(MainActivity.this.getExternalFilesDir(null), FILE_NAME);
    }

    //saving
    public void saveText(){
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            String text = "hello";
            fos = new FileOutputStream(getExternalPath());
            fos.write(text.getBytes());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        finally{
            try{
                if(fos!=null)
                    fos.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ex){
                Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Если я запрашиваю путь к файлу таким образом:

```
File file = new File(MainActivity.this.getExternalFilesDir(null), FILE_NAME);
String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

то получаю */storage/emulated/0/Android/data/packagename/files/document.txt*

В Device File Explorer в intellij idea файл можно найти в */storage/self/primary/Android/data/packagename/files/document.txt*

Проблема в том, что файл не виден, если попытаться найти его по первому пути, а второй путь вообще не доступен через файловую систему android. Я уверен, что файл создается корректно и существует, потому что могу его считать.

**Как я могу создать публичный файл в общедоступной директории через код java?**

Все решения, которые я смог найти, уже устарели. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Файл доступен в папке Android/data/package_name/files/  для пользователя и всех приложений.

Comment: @Style-7 о, да, действительно. Я проверял только SD-карту, но проверить на самом устройстве не подумал. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Файл доступен в папке Android/data/package_name/files/ для пользователя и всех приложений.
Спасибо комментатору!